# I dont know how to use awk in perl script?

Tags: perl

My awk command i like this

```
awk -F[][] '/Pattern.*.date/ {print $4}' $filename | xargs -0 -I {} grep {} $filename > /path/$filename
```

How do I use it in a perl script?
And also i have multiple file to check the pattern.
Please help.

Comment: You would call it the same way as you would call any other external command in perl. HAve you made any attempt to try it in perl? if so maybe provide your code and the issue you are facing.

Comment: Shell commands can be launched using `system`. Why you'd want to shell out to perform this task baffles me,

Answer (score 1):

There's a program called [a2p](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html) that translate `awk` scripts into Perl scripts. Here's the handy output...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
                        # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
                        # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
                        # process any FOO=bar switches

$FS = '\[';     # field separator from -F switch
$, = ' ';       # set output field separator
$\ = "\n";      # set output record separator

while (<>) {
    ($Fld1,$Fld2,$Fld3,$Fld4) = split(/[[\n]/, $_, -1);
    if (/Pattern.*.date/) {
        print $Fld4;
    }
}
```

I'm having a tough time trying to figure out what your awk script is attempting to doing:

```
awk -F[][] '/Pattern.*.date/ {print $4}' $filename
```

This says to look for all lines that contain the following:

- The word `Pattern` anywhere in the line.
- Followed by zero or more characters.
- Followed by one character.
- Followed by the word `date`.

Then print out the 4th *field* of each of those lines. Is this what you want? Usually, you'd use `/Pattern..*date/` for something like that.

Then, you have `-F[][]`. The `[][]` is suppose to be a regular expression, but the `[...]` is suppose to define a group of characters that can be represented (for example `[012345]` means any digit from `0` to `5`). However, on my system, it merely becomes `-F'['` as seen from the `a2p` results above.

Now, we get to:

```
 | xargs -0 -I {} grep {} $filename > /path/$filename
```

The `-0` means that the *file names* being passed to `xargs` are separated by the `NUL` character and not whitespace. This is usually used when the `find` command is executed:

```
find . -type f ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

This guarantees that file names with whitespace are not munged by `xargs`.

I don't see how it works here unless field #4 (whatever that is) has null characters embedded in it. Then, this looks like you're greping for those fields in the same file?

Besides, why do you want to call `awk` and `grep` in Perl when Perl is so much more powerful and faster? In fact, if you're using `grep` with `awk`, you can usually drop the `grep` and just use `awk`.

Give us an example of what `$filename` looks like and what you expect as the program to do.

Comment: `awk -F[][] 'BEGIN {print FS}'` does print `[][]`, and it appears to be the same as Perl's `split /[\]\[]/`